# Button is not removing user from its row. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. So, I am creating an app where I have a list of users that when a button is clicked, it need to remove that user from its list. The users are getting from a backend API. However, for some reason, the user is not being removed from the list when the "Confirm button" is clicked.

> Here is my code

**about.html**

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.users | filter : {id: userId}">

<a class="back" href="#/user">Back</a>

  <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
    Edit
  </button>

  <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>

  <a class="delete" ng-click="confirmClick(); confirmedAction($index);" confirm-click>Confirm</a>



  <div class="people-view">

    <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>

    <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>

    <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>

    <span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>


</div>

  <div class="list-view">

    <form>

      <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

        <legend>Main Users</legend>

        <b>First Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
        <br>

        <b>Last Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
        <br>

        <b>Email:</b>

        <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">



        <br>

      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> App.js

```
     var app = angular.module("MainPortal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);



      app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


       $scope.inactive = true;

    $scope.confirmedAction = function(index) {

    $scope.userInfo.users.splice(index.id, 1);

    location.href = '#/user';





};

});


app.directive('confirmClick', ['$q', 'dialogModal', function($q, dialogModal) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var ngClick = attrs.ngClick.replace('confirmClick()', 'true')
                .replace('confirmClick(', 'confirmClick(true,');


            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {

                if (msg===true) {
                    return true;
                }
          confirm?')

                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure you want to confirm?';

                dialogModal(msg).result.then(function() {
                    scope.$eval(ngClick);
                });

                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}])


    .service('dialogModal', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return function (message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {

        cancelButton = cancelButton===false ? false : (cancelButton || 
         'No');
        okButton = okButton ===false ? false : (okButton || 'Yes');


        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) 
          {

            angular.extend($scope, settings);

            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close(true);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
             };


            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div class="dialog-modal"> \
              <div class="modal-header" ng-show="modalTitle"> \
                  <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3> \
              </div> \
              <div class="modal-body">{{modalBody}}</div> \
              <div class="modal-footer"> \
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-
            show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> \
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" ng-
               show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> \
              </div> \
          </div>',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                settings: function() {
                    return {
                        modalTitle: title,
                        modalBody: message,
                        okButton: okButton,
                        cancelButton: cancelButton
                      };
                   }
                }
            });

          return modalInstance;
       }
     }])


    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/user", {
      controller: "HomeController",
    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
    })
     .when("/user/:id", {
    controller: "UserController",
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html"

   })
     .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/user'

    });

   });
```

> HomeController

```
    //var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people, $http) {
   // if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

      $scope.userInfo = response.data;



        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
   // }
});
```

> UserController

```
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {

        $scope.userId = $routeParams.id;
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This line `$scope.userInfo.users.splice(index.id, 1);` will only remove object from an array.

With this line `location.href = '#/user';` you will lose $scope and automatically $scope.userInfo.users, as you never remove object. 
Also line `location.href = '#/user';` will call HomeController
and there you have this call

```
people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
  $scope.userInfo = response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

which will retrive list of objects with object you previous remove (because you didn't send request to server to delete object).

In order to delete object, you have to execute call to server, some `$http.delete` method.

Comment: can you please show me a snippet of code prior to my code above, so I can understand how this method works.

Comment: How about to remove it only locally?

Comment: What is the purpose to remove it only locally?

Comment: Well, now I just don't want to delete the user. I just want to set that user to true when the confirm button is clicked.

Comment: Just remove this line `location.href = '#/user';` from confirmedAction function. 
Function confirmedAction should look like:
`$scope.confirmedAction = function(index) {
    $scope.userInfo.users.splice(index.id, 1);    
};`

This will remove object from list and stay on that page.